# How can I check if this function failed (should i check it)?

Tags: lua, cryptography, sha

I saw that under LuaCrypto we have this function `crypto.digest.new(dtype)`, and I saw the following explanation regarding the function:

> crypto.digest.new(dtype) Creates a new message digest object using the algorithm specified by dtype.

When I call this function should I check if it failed? how can I know it? where can I see what are the returned arguments from this function? and how can I check the returned arguments?

I know that this function returns in particular the value I want but I don't sure if I need to check if the function failed or not.

Answer (score 0):

The [LuaCrypto Manual](https://mkottman.github.io/luacrypto/manual.html#reference) states:

> **Error handling**
>
> The functions throw an error when known invalid parameters are passed, such as nonexistent digest/cipher and too large key or initialization vector. Otherwise, the functions return nil, error in case of runtime errors, such as incorrect input size when padding is enabled.

Knowing this we can then use [pcall](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pcall) to catch the error.

```lua
local success, object = pcall(crypto.digest.new(dtype))

if success and object then
    -- no error occurred. `object` is the new message digest object 
    for line in io.lines(some_file) do 
        object:update(line)
    end
    local md5_file = object:final()

else
   -- error occurred, `object` is the error information, if any is provided.
end
```

Wither you should check if the function completed properly is purely up to how you design your program. You did not provide any code showing how you are using, or plan to use, the function so "should I check it?" is not something I can answer.

---

Some suggested reading for Lua error handling:

[Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 2.3 – Error Handling](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.3)

[Programming in Lua: 8.4 – Error Handling and Exceptions](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html)

Comment: so if i pass "sh256" for example, is it ok?

Comment: if i call in this way: `crypto.digest.new("sha256")` is it can fail in some way? should i check if the returned value is not `nil` ?

Comment: @user123454321 no, `sha256` is not a supported `dtype`. the supported `dtypes` are `md5`, `md4`, `md2`, `sha1`, `sha`, `mdc2`, `ripemd160`

Comment: so if i send `sha1` for example, should i check if it failed ?

Comment: @user123454321 that is really up to how you want to handle the error if you want to catch it and handle where you called the function or if let it unwind the call stack and get handled at some other location.